# Flutter заполнить listview items в отдельном виджете

Tags: listview, flutter

Подскажите как заполнить items они у меня вынесены в отдельный виджет
или мне нужно там

Group84ItemWidget()

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class OrderTestWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  OrderTestWidget({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  @override
  _OrderTestWidgetState createState() => _OrderTestWidgetState();


}


class _OrderTestWidgetState extends State<OrderTestWidget> {


  var breedList = Order();
  void getCatData() async {
    var catJson = await CatAPI().getCatBreeds();
    print(catJson);
    var catMap = json.decode(catJson);
        print(catMap);
    setState(() {
      breedList = Order.fromJson(catMap);

      print(breedList.orderdata);  
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCatData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          AppLocalizations.of(context).ordertestwidgetTitle,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: AppColors.secondaryText,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            fontSize: 21,
          ),
        ),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 163, 238),
      ),
      body: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0),
        ),
        child: Column(       
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,

          children: [     
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child:  ListView.builder(
              itemCount: (breedList == null ||
              breedList.orderdata == null ||
              breedList.orderdata.length == 0)
              ? 0
              : breedList.orderdata.length,
              //  itemCount: 15,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {

              return GestureDetector(

                onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                return OrderDetaliWidget(catId: breedList.orderdata[index].id,catBreed: breedList.orderdata[index].name);
                }));},

                child: Card (child: Group84ItemWidget(),),

                );
              },
            ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Модель

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Order {
  String apistatus;
  String apimessage;
  List<OrderData> orderdata;
  Order({this.apistatus,this.apimessage,this.orderdata});

  factory Order.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
  var list = parsedJson['data'] as List;
   // print(list.toString());
    List<OrderData> dataList = list.map((i) => OrderData.fromJson(i)).toList();        
    return Order( 
           apistatus:parsedJson['api_status'].toString(),
           apimessage:parsedJson['api_message'],    
           orderdata: dataList
           );         
      }
}
```

Group84ItemWidget тут просто левые данные статично заполнены мне нужно их заполнить из запроса данными, и Group84ItemWidget Ссылается еще на Group81ItemWidget там gridview с юзерами

```
class Group84ItemWidget extends StatelessWidget { 
  void onButtonPressed(BuildContext context) { 
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(height: 300),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
       // color: AppColors.primaryText,
        boxShadow: [
         // Shadows.secondaryShadow,
        ],
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(35)),
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          //заголовок
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 11, top: 12),
              child: Text(
                AppLocalizations.of(context).group84itemwidgetTextTirleText,
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            //текст описания задания
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Container(
              width: 350,
              height: 75,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 11, top: 5),
              child: Text(
                AppLocalizations.of(context).group84itemwidgetTextSubtitleText,
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  fontSize: 11,
                  height: 1.2,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 90,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 11, top: 8, right: 8),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                //григ с воркерами
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 300,
                    height: 90,
                    child: GridView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                        maxCrossAxisExtent: 90.42969,
                        childAspectRatio: 1.48245,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                      ),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Group81ItemWidget(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,

                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,

                    //высота контейнера с ценой
                    child: Container(              
                     // color: AppColors.color4,
                      height: 70,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 0),
                      child: Column(                     
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: [
                          Align(
                            //текст цена за час
                            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                            child: Container(
                              width: 68,
                              height: 30,
                              child: Text(
                                AppLocalizations.of(context).group84itemwidgetBatttonAddText,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  fontSize: 28,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          //текст час или день
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Container(
                              width: 50,

                              child: Text(
                                AppLocalizations.of(context).group84itemwidgetLabelText,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  fontSize: 24,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 16, right: 8, bottom: 14),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 206,
                      height: 48,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 7),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: [
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                            child: Container(
                              width: 206,
                              height: 20,
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                              child: Stack(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Positioned(
                                    left: 19,
                                    bottom: 4,
                                    child: Text(
                                      AppLocalizations.of(context).group84itemwidgetTextAdressText,
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: AppColors.black,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Positioned(
                                    left: 0,
                                    bottom: 8,
                                    child: Image.asset(
                                      "assets/images/path-285.png",
                                      fit: BoxFit.none,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                            child: Container(
                              width: 191,
                              height: 16,
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 3),
                              child: Row(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                children: [
                                  Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                                    child: Container(
                                      width: 17,
                                      height: 17,
                                      child: Image.asset(
                                        "assets/images/path-287.png",
                                        fit: BoxFit.none,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                                    child: Container(
                                      width: 84,
                                      height: 15,
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, bottom: 1),
                                      child: Text(
                                        AppLocalizations.of(context).group84itemwidgetTextDateText,
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: AppColors.black,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                                    child: Container(
                                      width: 17,
                                      height: 17,
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 14),
                                      child: Image.asset(
                                        "assets/images/time.png",
                                        fit: BoxFit.none,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  //текст время
                                  Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                                    child: Container(
                                      width: 45,
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 6, bottom: 1),
                                      child: Text(
                                        AppLocalizations.of(context).group84itemwidgetTextTimeText,
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: AppColors.black,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 55,
                      height: 55,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 13),
                      child: Stack(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Positioned(
                            right: 0,
                            bottom: 0,
                            child: Container(
                              width: 55,
                              height: 55,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                boxShadow: [
                                  //тень круга с воркерами
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                                    offset: Offset(0, 0),
                                    blurRadius: 6,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              child: Image.asset(
                                "assets/images/path-301.png",
                                fit: BoxFit.none,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            right: 16,
                            bottom: 23,
                            child: Text(
                              AppLocalizations.of(context).group84itemwidgetTextWorkerText,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: AppColors.primaryText,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                fontSize: 24,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            right: 6,
                            bottom: 12,
                            child: Text(
                              AppLocalizations.of(context).group84itemwidgetTextWorkerCountText,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: AppColors.primaryText,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                fontSize: 12,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 66,
                      height: 44,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 13, top: 4),
                      child: FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () => this.onButtonPressed(context),
                        color: AppColors.primaryElement,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                        ),
                        textColor: Color.fromARGB(0, 0,0, 0),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                        child: Text(
                          AppLocalizations.of(context).group84itemwidgetButtonButton,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            fontSize: 14,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `Подскажите как заполнить items они у меня вынесены в отдельный виджет или мне нужно там` Пожалуйста сформулируйте внятный и понятный вопрос! Что нужно сделать, что уже сделано, в чем проблема.

Comment: Как я понял 1: вам необходимо получить данные (`items`) из `ListView.builder` и отобразить их в другом виджете.

Comment: Как я понял 2: вам необходимо получить данные (одного `item'a`) из `ListView.builder` и отобразить их в другом виджете при нажатии на `GestureDetector` этого `item'a`

Comment: Какой вариант правильный?

Comment: Мне нужно заполнить Group84ItemWidget() из api запроса) У меня ListItem разделен на три части , что то я не пойму как мне сами items заполнить код в другом файле , сейчас у меня просто выводит три card так как в api 3 записи , но нужно заполнить поля все на card.

Comment: Не получить а передать данные в items

Comment: breedList.orderdata это List<OrderData>

Comment: Тут все понятно это OrderDetaliWidget(catId: breedList.orderdata[index].id,catBreed: breedList.orderdata[index].name); это . OrderDetali в него так передаю

Comment: А где код с `Group84ItemWidget()`, и я что-то не вижу что `ListItem разделен на три части` где оно?

Comment: И ещё `Order` можно приложить, я нем могу предположить что у него внутри

Comment: Group84ItemWidget() тут как раз все поля адрес , дата , заголовок и проч )

Comment: сек сейчас выложу

Comment: Приложите весь связанный код

Comment: весь связанные это все приложение )))

Comment: Ну api запрос и модель, можно оставить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надеюсь, я все правильно понял по вопросу...

Странный вопрос, учитывая то что вы его уже решали с `OrderDetaliWidget()`. По архитектуре приложение очень тяжелое, и со временем его будет невозможно поддерживать. Я полагаю вы новичок и делаете проект во время обучения. [Вот материал который вам поможет.](https://flutter.su/tutorial/2-StatelessWidget-StatefulWidget#head)

---

В `OrderTestWidget()` заменил `Group84ItemWidget()` на `Group84ItemWidget(breedList.orderdata[index])`, для того чтобы он принимал нашу модель по индексу:

```
class _OrderTestWidgetState extends State<OrderTestWidget> {
  // ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ...
    child: ListView.builder(
      // ...
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return GestureDetector(
            // ...
            child: Card(
              child: Group84ItemWidget(breedList.orderdata[index]),
             ),
           );
         }
  }
}
```

В `Group84ItemWidget` был добавлен конструктор который при создании экземпляра ожидает нашу модель. И саму модель добавил как поле. Теперь в любом месте этого класса можно использовать данные конкретной модели:

```
class Group84ItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  Group84ItemWidget(this.item);
  final Order item;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ...
    Text(item.apimessage);
    // ...
  }
}
```

Аналогично делать в `Group84ItemWidget` с `Group81ItemWidget`. В этом случае связь будет такая: `OrderTestWidget -> Group84ItemWidget -> Group81ItemWidget`

Comment: Да это первое приложение )) на нем и обучаюсь , а нельзя все эти данные заполнять в OrderTestWidget или придется все в один большой файл сделать

Comment: OrderDetaliWidget() там понятно там по клику , так то я могу сделать и в одном файле могу все заполнить , сбило с толку что все в разных , такого я еще не делал

Comment: Вы можете только передавать данные между классами и методами и в процессе передачи изменять их, но заполнять посредством полей только.

Comment: @ДенисАкулов если Group84ItemWidget будет использоваться ещё где-то то можно оставить все так, но если единожды можно и в OrderTestWidget отдельный метод для этого сделать

Comment: Но вопрос в том какой потому будет у вас класс? 500+ строк...

Comment: Да , спасибо за ответ , думаю я пока не хочу все усложнять , перенесу все в один файл и заполню без проблем пусть он будет огромный , а то в коде потом не разобраться

Comment: Вот я затупил , решение очень простое создать переменные и все и заполнять их из OrderDetaliWidget . child: Card (child: Group84ItemWidget(name: breedList.orderdata[index].name,),), просто я зациклился что обязательно действие должно быть какое то

Comment: @ДенисАкулов бывает, вы же ещё учитесь)) Вам предстоит еще много узнать)

Comment: Просто подсел на Flatter не могу уснуть уже 2 дня))) это как наркотик

Comment: @ДенисАкулов но как по мне лучше передавать модель.

Comment: @ДенисАкулов Flutter интересный фреймворк)

Comment: два клика с модели скопировать)) модель я передал OrderTestWidget а это его маленькие части , ну круто их еще можно использовать в любом месте